# How do I link to the most recent version of a file on ruby-doc.org?

Tags: ruby

This link to [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html), for example, is pegged at Ruby 2.2.2, and there doesn't appear to be any `/latest` or `/current` path. Is there a path that always lands on the latest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the version from the path does the trick, leaving behind `/core`. The same works for `/stdlib` paths.

- 2.2.2: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html
- Latest: http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html